# Path for Windows10 Python 2.7 USB COM6

Tags: python, python-2.7, usb, hardware

I am trying to access my USB COM6 port on my windows10 using python2.7

The original code was for Linux was:

```
board = MultiWii("/dev/ttyUSB0")
```

My modified code for Windows is:

```
board = MultiWii("/COM6")
```

Is the correct code?

Comment: device "files" in windows have no path. they exist everywhere. probably just `com6` would do.

Comment: Try using [PuUSB](https://github.com/walac/pyusb)

Answer (score 0):

No, `/COM6` is not correct in Windows.  Try `COM6` and `\\.\COM6`.  To write the latter one inside a string literal in Python, you probably have to escape the back slashes, so you would write `"\\\\.\\COM6"`.